# Android Layout: What Should I use to formulate this Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android and I want to learn about android. I Just want to ask about lay outing. What should I use to formulate UI layout.

Deposits, Loans, Loan types, Available balance and Loan amount is just a ***TextView***

[image]

Comment: Relative layout

Comment: You should study how relative layout works...

Comment: Before you start, you should learn how to design layouts in android.
there are tons of free course available to getting start with android.
Here is the one which will help you to learn basics of android.

https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.. I'm not an android developer. but suddenly I become 1. because they given me an android project with 1 month time frame. Even thought I told them that I only know a little about android. Hope I can make it through stackoverflow and some other android references.. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John

You should go for `RelativeLayout`

To show border around your `RelativeLayout`

1) In your `res/drawable` folder, create a new file `background_border.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
    <!-- This is the stroke you want to define -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" 
            android:color="@android:color/black"/>
     <solid android:color="@android:color/white" /> // inner color
 </shape>
```

This drawable will be used to set rectangular border around your layout

2) Then create your layout as follows

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_border"> //setting square border here

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/lblDeposite"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:text="Deposits">

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/txtDepositeValue"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/lblShareCapital"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/lblDeposite"
       android:text="Share Capital">

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAvailableBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Available Balance"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtDepositeValue"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

   </RelativeLayout>

     //Similar to this layout create other two

    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutTwo"
      android:layout_below="@+id/layoutOne"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/background_border">

    //Your code for inside content will go here just like the layoutOne add 
        all your views here but with different ids

    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutThree"
      android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTwo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/background_border">

  //Your code for inside content will go here just like the layoutTwo add 
  all your views here but with different ids

    </RelativeLayout>

 </RelativeLayout> //Closing your parent view
```

3) Now since you want all the views clickable inside your Activity add `OnClickListener` for all the views

```
layoutOne.setOnClickListener(this);
layoutTwo.setOnClickListener(this);
layoutThree.setOnClickListener(this);
```

then override `onClick()` method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.layoutOne:
        //your code for first view click
        break;
        case R.id.layoutTwo:
        //your code for second view click
        break;
        case R.id.layoutThree:
        //your code for third view click
        break;           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` would be the best solution. You can also use `LinearLayout`, but it would require some nesting which is not good for performance.